# Selenium Webdriver - Trigger onchange before send all keys using SendKeys

Tags: selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

Chrome: Version 55.0.2883.87 m
Selenium: 2.43.1

I have a textbox that input integer number. When changing it value will show a alert popup. 
My problem is when using sendKeys to input "12". It input "1" then trigger alert, close alert: "2" appears. 
Expectation must be: input "12" properly without alert.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with [JavascriptExecutor](http://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-11-javascriptexecutor/)

```
    WebElement inputElement = null;//Your WebElement
    String valueToEnter = "12";
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]",inputElement,valueToEnter);
```

Comment: I tried, now 12 is inputted properly, but alert not show and nothing else happened.